# How to select date and time without the seconds in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

How do I select date and time without the seconds in mysql from a column with date value in a table ?
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" should be "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"

Comment: I found this answer very useful - just cut off seconds with LEFT(yourdatetime, 16) `https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123508`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS `formatted_date` FROM `table`;
```

Comment: @tfont: yes, indeed :)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp - for more flexible formatting like truncate to minutes, hours etc.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-07-16 22:23:15', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```

Comment: Returns 2011-July-16 22:23, which is probably not desired. Better use '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' with lower case %m for '2011-07-16 22:23'

Answer (score 7):

The proper solution is zero out seconds - and - preserve data type:

```
SELECT `datetime` - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM `datetime`) SECOND
FROM `some table`
```

If your datetime column contains microseconds then use this variant:

```
SELECT `datetime` - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND_MICROSECOND FROM `datetime`) SECOND_MICROSECOND
FROM `some table`
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35e728/1)

In theory, it should be faster than examples using date formatting functions.

Comment: Can you explain **why** that should be faster?

Comment: @nico using date arithmetic should be faster than date format-parse functions in theory.

Comment: That does not answer my question - "should be faster" is still pretty vague