# How to write mysql scipt to filter data for a given datetime without second?

Tags: php, mysql

I have datetime data like this:

```
2012-07-30 09:18:20
2012-07-30 09:18:20
2012-07-30 09:18:22
2012-07-30 09:18:23
2012-07-31 19:08:14
2012-07-31 19:08:15
2012-07-31 19:08:15
```

How to get count of data with date 2012-07-30 09:18 (without second information) ?

SELECT COUNT * WHERE ........

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718759/how-to-select-date-and-time-without-the-seconds-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(*), DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as my_date FROM YOUR_TABLE     [WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') = <date needed>]
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE('datecolumn','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i');
```

for more info see mySQL : [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM my_table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(datetime_column, ':', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variant -

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  datetime_column - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM datetime_column) SECOND
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

This will give you total count, dates in output.

```
select count(*),DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') 
from MY_TABLE
group by DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

If you want to use where for single date (suppose you are passing variable from PHP)

```
select count(*),DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') 
from MY_TABLE 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2000-02-14' ;
```

Hope this help.