# Removing time from DataTables result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, datatables

I am looking to remove 00:00:00 from the database result.  Normally I can do it BUT I am using DataTables (which is new to me) so I do not know how to do it.

The date of birth display like

```
1996-04-27 00:00:00
```

But I need it like

```
27-04-1996
```

Is anyone familiar with dataTables that can advise?

I have the code below in the server_processing.php for DataTables.  It is not as simple as just using `"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS formated_date FROM table"` unfortunately!

```
    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */
$aColumns = array('C_ID', 'C_Title', 'C_Surname', 'C_Forename', 'C_DOB', 'C_ID', 'C_Ref');

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "C_ID";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "Table1";
```

And

```
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhereNew
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
```

**UPDATE**

Comment: What database are you using Sql-Server MySql or something else?

Comment: You get the time with seconds and then you want to remove it? How about not getting the time at all? Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718759/how-to-select-date-and-time-without-the-seconds-in-mysql) (assuming you're using MySQL)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I am using MySql.  Unfortunately it isn't as easy as the solution you linked to @Nath.  I am using DataTables.  I have edited my original question to show some of the code.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I see. Is the time required in the Db itself?

Comment: It isn't but I am doing work on an existing system and have been left to do it myself (i am not a php/mysql developer) so I am having trouble.  The db field is datetime and I cannot change it as I would need to alter the system all the way through where it is called.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. You should use the firebug console and make a screen shot of the json result the datatables ajax request returns. Like I did in your last question. Also, as @davidkonrad said, it would be helpful to see the part of your javascript where the initialization of the datatable happens. Please add this info to your question, not my answer, since it helps others to follow our progress and may come up with better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You won't like that, but the best place to fix this is in the javascript definition of the table by adding a mRender function:

```
  $('#demotable').dataTable({
      "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "aTargets": [0]
      }, {
        "aTargets": [1],
        "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
          if (data === null) return 'N/A';
          if (data === '') return 'N/A';
          if (data == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') return 'N/A';
          var tdat = data.split(' ');
          var tedat = tdat[0].split('-');
          return tedat[2] + '-' + tedat[1] + '-' + tedat[0];
        }
      }, ]
    }
  );
```

Why is that so?

Because this would leave the original data intact and just SHOW a modified output. The cool thing is that sorting still works because it uses the original date!

[Look at this plunker and try sorting the Date-column](http://plnkr.co/edit/wac2PgidiuOo6PDrhK76?p=preview)

**UPDATE**

This is image of the output

[image: Image of Output]

Comment: Hello again! Thanks for the help!  I have changed #demotable to #mytablename and also line 5 to [4] which is my table col with the date in but I get an error  "DataTables warning (table id = 'example-22'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0"

Comment: I added extra table cols into your example on plunker but it breaks the rendering.  My table has 5 cols and the date is in the 4th col.

Comment: Forked the plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/oNBPT9hN12IJP4kgdCnu?p=preview You need as many columndefs as there are columns in your table. Don't forget to set aTargets. Implement your changes and if does not work, send me the forked Plunker, so i can use my mad fixing skillz :-)

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I have amended it, it works on Plunker but not on my site!  http://plnkr.co/edit/xod9mJsrndr5oxzjudKj?p=preview  The error I get is DataTables warning (table id = 'example-22'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0

Comment: This is definitely related to getting  less fields from your server than you have columns in your database. Just remove  THs until the error does not show up anymore. This may give you a hint. Elese post a screen shot of your jsondata from the server and use a paint program to gray out critical information. Leave just the data structure intact. A single demo entry will do.

Comment: I have tried taking out/adding in <th> but with no luck.  I have added a screenshot of the output I get which shows you how it is displayed on the site!

Comment: Posted my last comment accidentally to your original question, because this thread is getting a bit confusing too.

Comment: Hi, I have another issue (surprise, surprise) link is here, can you help?  I don't know if you can PM on here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917610/complicated-mysql-query-in-php-page