# Complicated mySQL query in php page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If you have seen my previous requests you will see I am a TOTAL NOOB with php and mySQL.  I wish I wasn't even doing this but I have been dumped in the deep end by people that have let me down. It is 1 day away from "completion" and I am left to pick up and mend the pieces of this system I have which doesn't fully function!

I have tried to explain this as logically and clearly as possible.  If you need clarification please let me know and I will do my best!

Thanks in advance for any help as I am now desperate to get this thing done!

I have 3 issues!

**ISSUE1**

Matching Keys
(x)

```
TABLE1

|        C_ID        |       C_Eth_O   (x)     |
+--------------------+-------------------------+
|        234         |             8           |
|        341         |             11          |
|        440         |             2           |


TABLE2

|        Eth_ID  (x)    |        C1_Eth_O        |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|            2          |         Label2         |
|            8          |         Label8         |
|            9          |         Label9         |
|            11         |         Label11        |
```

I need to list all the "C1_Eth_O" values in a multi select list.  The user will make multiple selections from that list.  When submitted I need to get the "Eth_ID" value(s) and return all the value(s) from TABLE1 where any of the selected options "C_Eth_O" = "Eth_ID". Each "C_ID" can only have one "C_Eth_O".

**ISSUE2**

```
Matching Keys    
(x)
(o)


TABLE1

|        C_ID   (x)   |
+---------------------+
|        234          |
|        341          |
|        440          |


TABLE3

|        Ail_ID  (o)      |        Ali_Label        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|           1             |        Label1           |
|           2             |        Label2           |
|           3             |        Label3           |
|           4             |        Label4           |
|           5             |        Label5           |
|           6             |        Label6           |


TABLE4

|        CA_ID         |       C1_ID    (x)     |      Ail1_ID    (o)    |
 +---------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|           1          |            234         |            1           |
|           2          |            341         |            4           |
|           3          |            341         |            6           |
|           4          |            440         |            2           |
```

I need to list all the "Ali_Label" values from TABLE3 in a multi select list.  The user will make multiple selections from that list.  When submitted I need to get the "Ail_ID" value(s) from TABLE3 and return all the value(s) from TABLE1 where any of the selected match in TABLE4 "Ali1_ID" = "Ail_ID" & "C1_ID" = "C_ID".  Each "C_ID" can have multiple "Ail_ID" values

**ISSUE3**

```
Matching Keys    
(x)
(o)
(-)


TABLE1

|        C_ID   (x)   |
+---------------------+
|        234          |
|        341          |
|        440          |


TABLE3

|        Ail_ID  (o)     |        Ali_Label        |
+------------------------+-------------------------+
|           1            |        Label1           |
|           2            |        Label2           |
|           3            |        Label3           |
|           4            |        Label4           |
|           5            |        Label5           |
|           6            |        Label6           |



TABLE5

|        R_ID           |        C1_ID  (x)     |        Cf1_ID   (-)   |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|           1           |           234         |           768         |
|           2           |           234         |           854         |
|           3           |           234         |           768         |
|           4           |           440         |           854         |



TABLE6


|        CA_ID         |       Cf_ID    (-)     |      Ail1_ID    (o)    |
 +---------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|           1          |            768         |            1           |
|           2          |            854         |            4           |
|           3          |            768         |            6           |
|           4          |            880         |            2           |
```

I need to list all the "Ali_Label" values from TABLE3 in a multi select list.  The user will make multiple selections from that list.  When submitted I need to get the "Ail_ID" value(s) from TABLE3 and return all the value(s) from TABLE1 where any of the selected "Ali_ID" = "Ail1_ID"    &    "C1_ID" = "C_ID"    &    "Cf1_ID" = "Cf_ID".  Each "C_ID" can have multiple "Cf1_ID" values AND each "Cf_ID" can have multiple "Ail1_ID" values.

I have the system working returning simple queries such as

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE C_ID = 234
```

but nothing with multiple tables and multiple results per C_ID!

Thanks again!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You should also search for the JOIN order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISSUE 1 -

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table 2 ON table1.C_Eth_O = table2.Eth_ID
```

ISSUE 2 -

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table4 ON table1.C_ID = table4.C1_ID INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.Ail_ID = table4.Ail1_ID
```

ISSUE 3 -

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table5 ON table1.C_ID = table5.C1_ID INNER JOIN table6 ON table5.Cf1_ID = table6.Cf_ID INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.Ail_ID = table6.Ail1_ID
```